# Postgres parallel queries

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, parallel-processing

How can we execute multiple queries written in stored proc in parallel.:

Create table a as select * from x;

Create table b as select * from y;

Create table c as select * from z;

For ex these three queries should be executed concurrently

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that.

You would have to start those queries in three distinct database sessions; that is the way to do parallelization in PostgreSQL.